How to use environment variables in root files of you SvelteKit project?
I have a SvelteKit project using TypeScript with a .env file at the root. At the root I added a drizzle.config.ts file. When I add the following on top:
_import { DATABASE_HOST} from '$env/static/private';_

then both WebStorm and VSCode give me the following error:
_Cannot find module '$env/static/private' or its corresponding type declarations._

This also happens when I start a completely new SvelteKit project and add the files as mentioned above, so I suppose it would be easy to reproduce the issue.
I've restarted VsCode, Webstorm and my computer. I've tried to do it using a new project. None of these things worked. Many posts tell me to change some configurations files. I tried some of these but they didn't work. I also feel like that shouldn't be the solution since there should be an out of the box solution?
Could anyone explain why this does not work, and what the right way would be to use Environment variables in root files in SvelteKit?
Thanks in advance!

Same issue except I’m using import { env } from ‘$env/static/private’;

You can only use the $env modules in the code of the SvelteKit application (generally things in src) because that is processed by the build which injects the variables accordingly.
In other files you have to use whatever mechanism your runtime executing the file provides for accessing environment variables, e.g. in Node there is process.env.

Wait so how would you go about setting up a database or api connection with environment variables in SvelteKit then? Would you place the .env file somewhere else besides the root, or would you use process.env instead of an .env file? The documentation on it is confusing to me: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-static-private
Or is it just that the Drizzle config has to be done at the root but other environment variables can be set elsewhere?

@SamSabin: The location where those files can be defined and how they are processed is limited. Since the Drizzle config is not processed by SvelteKit, you probably need to use process.env there (even if you were to move it elsewhere that would not change). .env files should generally also be at the root, elsewhere they might will not be found by default (though I have never tried that & see little reason for doing this).

Why doesn’t SvelteKit process the config file?

I was following this tutorial where they reference the SvelteKit env modules directly in the drizzle config: https://sveltekit.io/blog/drizzle-sveltekit-integration
I noticed that the tutorial is a bit old and some of the info is outdated. Have things changed now so that you can no longer reference env modules from config files in root?

It depends. If you only ever call Drizzle from within SvelteKit, it should work, but if you e.g. set up the DB separately or use certain tools that try to use the config directly, that probably will not work.

What does that look like practically? I’m a bit lost in the abstract nature of what we’re talking about.

E.g. code you put into src/hooks.server.js is executed by SvelteKit, so if you do DB migrations there in code by calling migrate, all modules, including the environment variables, should be there. If you use some other tool like Drizzle Kit or a custom script, which you call manually from the command line, this will not be the case.

Gotcha, that makes a lot of sense, thank you for the info. What would you recommend for this structure then? Do you think I should use the $env modules for the config file, and only call things from the SvelteKit application, or should I use process.env? Also is there anywhere I can read more about the limitations with how SvelteKit processes data? As it is now, I’m having the same issues as op, where typescript can’t seem to find the module. If I wanted to do it the same way as the tutorial, would I just have to call the migrations through Svelte directly instead of the command line?

I would probably just use process.env directly for top level files that are not guaranteed to be processed by SvelteKit, then command line tools should work. Documentation wise, I only know of the $env modules reference. The tutorial makes me want to punch my screen, if you want any help with it, please contact the author.

Hahaha fair enough. I think that’s a good way to go about it so I preserve full functionality. Perhaps I’ll also create a question around the SvelteKit build process with modules to see if there is some more info out there. Thanks so much for all your help! I’m loving SvelteKit so far, just been a bit frustrated with the lack of documentation with integrations with third party software. Svelte documentation itself is great but svelte needs more love from integrations. Seems Next.js has a much bigger community surrounding those types of tutorials/documentation.

I went ahead and asked a specific question outlining some of these issues here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78645510/how-do-you-use-process-env-in-sveltekit

For sveltekit:
Place the .env on the root directory of project.
Prepend private (server only) static variables with SECRET_
Prepend public (client too) static variables with PUBLIC_
Example .env:
SECRET_DB_HOST=myhost
SECRET_PASSWORD=mypass

You can then import and use:
import { SECRET_DB_HOST, SECRET_PASSWORD } from '$env/static/private';

You can verify that sveltekit indeed injects these variables into .svelte-kit/ambient.d.ts
