How do you use process.env in SvelteKit?
I'm trying to connect a postgresql database with SvelteKit via Drizzle, using their nodejs package. I'm having a problem importing the database environment variables into the Drizzle config.
At first, I thought I could use SvelteKit's built-in modules ($env/static/private) via the SvelteKit documentation: Module Docs and Environment Variable Tutorial
My first attempt at a drizzle config looked like this:
drizzle.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'drizzle-kit';
import { env } from '$env/static/public';

export default defineConfig({
  schema: './src/lib/server/schema.ts',
  out: './drizzle',
  dialect: 'postgresql',
  dbCredentials: {
    host: env.DB_HOST,
    port: env.DB_PORT,
    user: env.DB_USER,
    password: env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: env.DB_NAME,
  },
});

But this implementation gives me the following error: _Cannot find module '$env/static/private' or its corresponding type declarations._. I researched this error and found the following Stack Overflow question addressing this problem: How to use environment variables in root files of you SvelteKit project?
From what I understand, because the Drizzle config is in the root, it is being processed by Vite before SvelteKit processes it? So either you have to move the Drizzle config to a nested folder within SvelteKit (Here's an example, except it's using the planetscale package instead of integrating directly), or you have to use process.env directly, despite $env/static/private having access to process.env variables (Here's an example of this method, again unfortunately dated). Here is also another example from a tutorial that seems to imply that you can have Drizzle config in root while also using $env/static/private, but the other Stack Overflow question seems to contradict this, and this example is also using the old version of Drizzle config syntax.
The problem I'm having is actually implementing process.env.
Do I need to import dotenv (I was under the impression that Svelte already includes it, but I'm not sure if I need to invoke it explicitly)? How do I make sure Typescript recognizes the typing of the env variables? Is it best practice to use process.env, or a nested folder format with the db (the other Stack Overflow question I referenced said that if I use a nested folder method then I won't be able to use Drizzle tools like drizzle-kit.), or is there really a way to use $env/static/private with config files in root?
I tried to follow a more generic example of process.env for Node using this Stack Overflow Question, but I'm quite confused. Here's my most recent attempt (still using a file in root), which gives me all kinds of errors:
import { defineConfig } from 'drizzle-kit';

declare var process : {
    env: {
      DB_HOST: string,
      DB_PORT: string,
      DB_USER: string,
      DB_PASSWORD: string,
      DB_NAME: string
    }
  }

export default defineConfig({
  schema: './src/lib/server/schema.ts',
  out: './drizzle',
  dialect: 'postgresql',
  dbCredentials: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  },
});

What is the best practice for using environment variables in SvelteKit, and how do I implement it?

Svelte is based on Vite. If you need to run standalone scripts with Vite run-time config, like import aliases, see vite-node. Note that you can access only environment variables declared public this way. process.env works normally for any JavaScript file.

My question is specifically about database credentials which are private variables so unfortunately I can't use vite-node. I'm already attempting to use process.env like normal in my code. Do you know what I'm doing wrong with my implementation?

This is missing how your code interacts with the config (i.e. how e.g. the DB is initialized and used) and the specific errors you get. (Also avoid multiple questions in one, otherwise this may get closed.)

The code looks good. I suggest you start with a standalone self-hosted JavaScript file that connects to the database, and then work from there to more complex integrations.

@brunnerh I apologize if I've formatted things incorrectly. I really tried to be very specific by providing my code example, documentation, and specific use-case so as not to be broad. I think those clarifying questions are essential for solving this nuanced problem with integration. With all the conflicting/outdated information, anyone else trying to solve this problem will need some of that contextual information. I will add some more information about database initialization and error messaging. I was hoping that I was just missing something glaring in the code but it seems more nuanced

The given code is not the problem. As mentioned before, the SvelteKit modules only exist within the context of SvelteKit's execution. process.env exists in any Node execution, but the variables may also not be there if they need to be loaded e.g. from an .env file (which might require manual loading e.g. via the dotenv package.). Hence the important part if how/where the config is used. And without the specific errors or a description of what exactly happens, it is hard to tell what might be wrong.

It seems that there was an issue with my code (I wasn't parsing DB Port number to an int). I'm now able to interact with the config with Drizzle. I would still appreciate answers to any of the other questions concerning best practices if anyone is aware of them

I could not believe it when I discovered after reading the example for the 100th time, that I did not realise in sveltekit you must prepend the variables in static .env (in the project root) with PUBLIC_ and PRIVATE_.
Anything else is simply not injected and apparently no other method (vite, node) works out of the box at least.
So you can use the .env file to store the url or credentials and then
import { SECRET_DATABASE_URL } from '$env/static/private';

As for best practises obviously storing sensitive info in the .env is a better way. If you're using git make sure .env is in .gitignore (sveltekit did this automatically for me).
I do not think that if a file is on root this magic is not available, especially since you import it at some point to do the querying but my db config/instantiation is in $lib. I used knex but the process looks similar.
